# Is it possible to create a custom object type in Doxygen?

Tags: doxygen

I want to use Doxygen to document an HTTP API and have the descriptions of HTTP queries with parameters, return results etc similar to the description of classes. So what I need is a `\query` structural command which can be followed by `\brief`, `\param`, `\return` and so on and have a corresponding tab "Queries" in the top navigation menu. In other words I need a 100% replication of `\class` but simply with a different name. Is this possible and how?

Answer (score 0):

Don't think its possible to do this as cleanly as you hope for, but a way I would accomplish this is by using groups.

```
/**
 * \defgroup query Queries
 */
```

Then document each query as a group in the `query` group

```
/**
 * \defgroup getUser Get User by Id
 * \ingroup query
 * \brief Some brief
 * \param Id user id
 * \return User for given id
 */
```

Now you need to add a tab to the `query` group in the navigation menu.

First generate a doxygen layout file using `doxygen -l`. Then in your doxyfile set `LAYOUTFILE = DoxygenLayout.xml`.

Finally change your DoxygenLayout.xml file to add the new tab:

```
<navindex>
   ...
   <tab type="user" visible="yes" title="Queries" url="@ref query" intro=""/>
```